# Disable collapsibility of DataGrid group headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, datagrid

I have a UWP application with a DataGrid defined in xaml.

The DataGrid contains grouped data. When it displays, there is a downward-facing carat to the left of the group headings that can be clicked, causing that group to collapse. As far as I can see, this is a default behavior that we didn't specifically ask for.

My customer doesn't like this and wants me to remove the functionality. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the functionality by modifying the [`DataGridRowGroupHeader.HeaderStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagridrowgroupheader?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable). Simple way is to add `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`. This will disable the expander so the group wont get Collapsed.

```
<controls:DataGrid>
   <controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
     <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">     
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
     </Style>
   </controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

## Edit

> Although it doesn't eliminate the indicator.

Here's new style with removing indicator

```
<controls:DataGrid>
    <controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                        <Grid x:Name="RowGroupHeaderRoot" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">


                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">


                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle x:Name="IndentSpacer" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Grid.Column="2" Height="12" Width="12" Template="{StaticResource ToggleButtonTemplate}"
                                IsTabStop="False" Margin="12,0,0,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PropertyNameElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding PropertyNameVisibility}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PropertyValueElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ItemCountVisibility}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <Rectangle x:Name="CurrencyVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="FocusVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                                <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Transparent"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="2"/>
                            </Grid>


                            <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. This does prevent the group from collapsing, which is good, although it doesn't eliminate the indicator.

Comment: Okay will add that too

Comment: I have modified as per your request. Kindly verify the same